# Android get Dialog text color

Tags: android, dialog, textcolor

I have a custom DialogPreference:

```
public class MyDiagPreference extends DialogPreference {
    public MyDiagPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.my_diag_preference);
    }
}
```

This is my_diag_preference.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the text color of the TextView is wrong in Android API 10.
The text color is always black.

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80P14.jpg

Anyway when in my app I use an AlertDialog (not custom) the text color changes properly between different android APIs.

So,
is there a way to get via xml the color of the text used by a Dialog, so that I can use that value to set the colorText of my EditText above?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution. I found the answer looking at this file:
*sdk/platforms/android-10/data/res/values/themes.xml*

I added `style="?android:attr/panelTextAppearance"` to the EditText.

So the above piece of xml becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test TextView"
        style="?android:attr/panelTextAppearance" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your text color in the `TextView` itself and you'll get the text color as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Test TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: using this I get only a black rectangle. I would like to set the textColor of the EditText, not using a fixed color like #000000, but using something like (I'm inventing the following) @android:color/dialogText

Comment: different apis use different background colors, so using a fixed value won't solve the problem.