# Android AlertDialog produces black text with black background

Tags: android

I am having an issue with a custom view in a dialog on android API 10.

I use `AlertDialog.Builder` to construct my dialog. I include a custom view panel using the `setView` command on the builder.

This works on most of the API's I've tested with. The style changes somewhat from device to device, but that is what I want, for the style to match the device default.

My problem is that on API 10, any text that is in my custom view shows up as black on a black background.

Any text I insert using `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage()` appears correctly.

What magical attribute/style is the dialog builder using to determine text appearance?

My app's theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Here is my onCreateDialog method:

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status_dialog, null);
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_status);
    mConnectedDeviceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_connected_device);

    MainService.ServiceState state = null;
    if (getArguments().containsKey(SERVICE_STATUS_ARG_KEY)) {
        state = (MainService.ServiceState) getArguments().getSerializable(SERVICE_STATUS_ARG_KEY);
    }
    setState(state);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setMessage("This will show up just fine.");
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.status_title));
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_back_button_text, null);
    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.dialog_connect_to_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mListener.onDialogConnectTo();
        }
    });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Here's my fragment_status_dialog layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="18dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/status_starting"
    android:id="@+id/text_status"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/status_connected_to_unknown"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/text_connected_device"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_status"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_status"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Note, I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505312/2350083 but it didn't fix it.

[image: ex]

Comment: Try calling `AlertDialog#setInverseBackgroundForced(true)`.

Comment: Alex, this solution seems to work for me! Thank you! I've tested it so far on devices using API 10,13,15,19

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `AlertDialog#setInverseBackgroundForced(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply setting the color of the text? Ex:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/status_starting"
    android:id="@+id/text_status"/>
```

The TextView is using the default text color of the device (or the app). If you set the color specifically to the TextView it will be overriden on devices irrespective of the API.

Comment: The different API's have different styles. For example, my Dell Streak 7 shows all dialogs with a white background.